# Camera2Basic : Application:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am using the [Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) by Google to test an application in Android Studio. I am getting this error when I run the project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }

}
```

**What I did**

1) I added `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig.

2) Also tried by adding `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"
```

with

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

in build.gradle file. Now, it's working. I don't know the reason. Please edit this answer if anybody knows the reason. It'll be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: An answer is an answer. Even if 1 line is enough.